# Fill in the missing integers in table using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as :

[image]

I want to insert the missing digits like 2,4,5 and make the corresponding values to be 0.
Like this:

[image]

I don't want to use loops(as my SQL version doesn't support it). Is there any way this can be attained in SQL?

Comment: you can create another cte/temp table with all 12 months and the amount as 0. you can left join cte with existing table and insert only records where right side table value is null

Comment: And how do we create another cte/temp table without recurssion? I Couldnt find a good solution for that.

Comment: Use `generate_series()`

Answer (score 0):

I Never work with `postgresql`. But the logic should be something like below.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_data
   (
      Month int,
      amount bigint
   ) 

insert into temp_location
select 1,0 union
select 2,0 union
select 3,0 union
select 4,0 union
select 5,0 union
select 6,0 union
select 7,0 union
select 8,0 union
select 9,0 union
select 10,0 union
select 11,0 union
selecct 12,0
```

You can Insert only records which is missing in your table using left Join

```
insert into yourtable
select td.Months,td.Amount
from temp_data td
left join yourtable yt on td.Months = yt.months
where yt.months is null
```